# stl style algorithm: how to manage output iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stl-algorithm

if I need to write some algorithm in stl style and prototype is something like:

```
template<typename RAIter>
void my_algo(RAIter begin, RAIter end, RAIter out);
```

looks similar to e.g. std::copy

the question about output iterator,
does this mean that caller code should allocate enough capacity?
and algorithm uses ++out only? without any checks.
or algorithm should add new elements? how?

Comment: I think your algorithm should take care of needed allocation for output iterator. At least, IMO, it's the most intuitive way.

Comment: STL style algorithms generally cannot allocate new sequence elements nor make any bounds checks (specialized iterators can).

Answer (score 1):

If you algorithm only gets an output iterator type it won't be able to do much with it because output iterators can't even compared for equality. Probably you meant an interface like this:

```
template<typename RAIter, typename WIter>
WIter my_algo(RAIter begin, RAIter end, WIter out);
```

The contract of you algorithm shall specify how many elements can be written at most in terms of `std::distance(begin, end)` and `out` shall allow at least as many values to be assigned. That is, there is no special handling of output iterators in algorithm.

Note, however, that it is in general necessary to return output iterators to indicate where writing of objects stopped.

Comment: you are right, output type should meet OutputIterator concept and should be added as second template parameter

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the contract you want for your library. In either case your caller must be aware of memory implications, throw behaviour, error scenarios. I would suggest making it explicit in your documentation that the precondition  be that **out** points to beginning of at least distance(end - begin) elements. The elements may not be necessarily in a valid state.
The reasoning behind this is:

1. Callers are already aware of how much memory they require since you mentioned your algorithm will be similar to copy.
2. Leaving the responsibility on caller to allocate memory helps them give more flexibility of allocating the memory they want. They may require tweaks and optimizations while allocating memory for the objects. If you decide that your function allocates memory, then you will also need to provide an additional parameter for the allocator.
3. Simplifies the responsibility of your function. You need not worry about out of memory scenarios and your function can focus on it's algorithm.